# How to send flash messages using android

Tags: android, sms

I am sending SMS by using
Code:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

It's working fine and successfully sends a standard SMS that is automatically saved in recipient mobile inbox.

I want send the SMS as flash(notification) SMS. By this I mean that the message should be displayed immediately on recipient mobile screen but not stored.

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Apparently, [this app][1] can send flash SMS (though not very reliably?).

If this is possible at all, it's likley to use the sendDataMessage method of SmsManager.


  [1]: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=816002&referrerid=0

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123125/class-0-sms-flash-sms-on-android

Answer (score 0):

For sending Flash SMS the Modem used should be compatible to send Flash Messages.

try sending AT+CMGF? command.This will read the value stored by modem for command CMGF Message Format

if AT+CMGF? returns 0 i.e it is in PDU mode (where entire TP data units are used)

then it is compatible

else if it returns 1 then it is in text mode (where the body of
the message and its headers are given as separate parameters)