# android: Sending temporary sms to a mobile

Tags: android, sms, sms-gateway

Is it possible to send an sms to a device or an android mobile such that the sms gets deleted after a specified time (say 30 mins) by itself? 
The code I am using to send sms is:`

```
      public class SMSTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
String str, str1;   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Button btn;
    final EditText etb, etb1;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    etb=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    etb1=(EditText)findViewById( R.id.phNum);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            str=etb.getText().toString();
            str1=etb1.getText().toString();

            sendSms( str1, str);    

        }
    });
}

private void sendSms(String phonenumber, String message)
{
        SmsManager x=SmsManager.getDefault();
        x.sendTextMessage(phonenumber,  null, message, null, null);
}

public void display(View v)
{
      final Button bt;
      bt=(Button) v;
      bt.setText("Hello");

}
```

}

Comment: I dont think its possible

Comment: Self Destroying sms.? No its not possible unless you have an application installeed at the receiving end that itself deletes the sms after 30 minutes.

Comment: so how can we delete an sms after 30 mins from a device from a specified number?

Comment: get the thread id of the received sms and start an alrammanager that would invoke iteself after 30 minutes and here you pass the query to delete the sms with the thread id you received.

Answer (score 0):

A Class 0 SMS will display on the screen, and will be deleted unless the user chooses to save it, if you can manage to get round Android trying to prevent you sending Class 0 SMSes.  More information is at [Class 0 SMS (flash SMS) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123125/class-0-sms-flash-sms-on-android)