# UCS-2 enabled class 0 sms for android

Tags: android, sms, ucs2

I am looking for a way to send class 0 sms without messing with UCS-2 encoding.

The answers in the thread [Class 0 SMS (flash SMS) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123125/class-0-sms-flash-sms-on-android), seem to be messing with UCS-2 encoding, as normal text is sent and received well, but languages that require UCS-2 encoding appears as junk characters.

I.E.

When sending, [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTX8m.png]

In both cases, [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYxS.png]  is received.

Both, [ Second Answer in thread, stackoverflow.com/a/9424185/3082310 ]

```
byte[] encodedMessage = pdus.encodedMessage;
// byte[0] = mtiByte
// byte[1] = TP Message Reference
// byte[2] = length of source phone
// byte[3..length] = phone
// protocol identifier
int msgLen = encodedMessage[2] / 2;
// +2 -> length of source phone
// +2 -> for 91 after the length
// +1 -> TP PID
int indexTPDCS = msgLen + 5;
byte TPDCS = encodedMessage[indexTPDCS];

byte[] changedMessage = encodedMessage.clone();
// Set bit 4 to 1 using OR (|), indicating there is a message class
// Set bit 0 and 1 to 0 using AND (&), indicating class 0
byte newTPDCS = (byte) ((TPDCS | 0x10) & 0xFC); // Flash SMS
changedMessage[indexTPDCS] = newTPDCS; // Class 0
```

And, [ ZeroSMS, github.com/virtualabs/ZeroSMS ]

```
/* change class to Class 0 *
int size;
size = (int)pdus.encodedMessage[2];
size = (size/2) + (size%2);
pdus.encodedMessage[size+5] = (byte)0xF0;
```

Seem to give the same results.

Any ideas on where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a need for if-then or switch-case statements:
For 7-bit coding, as in english

use `(byte)0xF0`

For 16-bit encoding, UCS-2 encoding

use `(byte) 0x18`

Otherwise, junk characters appear if you enter unsupported language.