# How to dismiss/close class 0 message dialogs in Android

Tags: java, android, dialog

Is there any way to dismiss/close/cancel or at least *programatically/automatically* anwer the **class 0 messages** also called **flash messages** in android?

Class 0 Message dialog:

[image]

I have gone through the following forums but no definitive answer is given.

- androidforums.com/threads/class-0-zero-messages.331720/
- www.droidforums.net/threads/can-you-block-class-0-messages.281093/

The following software (**Notification History Pro**) claims to have solved this problem.

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nh

I have used the free version but it doesn't provide the "automatically close class 0/ flash message dialog" feature.
I have checked every possible answer on stackoverflow.com but they don't provide the answer to my question.

- [Class 0 SMS (flash SMS) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123125/class-0-sms-flash-sms-on-android).

I have also tried the following answers on dismissing the **USSD/system dialogs** on android with no avail. It only works for USSD/system dialogs but not for "**class 0 messages**".

- stackoverflow.com/questions/24013790/how-to-dismiss-system-dialog-in-android
- stackoverflow.com/questions/24875914/a-new-way-to-manage-ussd-dialogs-in-android
- stackoverflow.com/questions/24013790/how-to-dismiss-system-dialog-in-android
- stackoverflow.com/questions/9908020/how-to-close-cancel-dismiss-a-system-dialog-programmatically-android

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: The pro version of the Android application I referenced solves the problem. That said, I need to implement the feature in my own application.